Bizarre login behavior on android Chrome for mobile app using OAuth PKCE with SAML/SSO
Currently working on a mobile app on android 14 which authenticates to a server using OAuth PKCE with SAML/SSO
Here is what should be happening:

user clicks connect to server on app
app initiates WebAuthenticator which in turn launches the custom Chrome tabs browser
browser navigates to the /oauth/authroize end-point
server detects user is not authenticated and redirects to the /accounts/signin page
user asks to authenticate with SAML/SSO provider
user authenticates with the provider
The SAML assertion response comes back and we redirect again to /oauth/authorize (redirect specified in relaystate parameter)
server detects user is logged in and we redirect back to the app using something like app://callback?code=12345&state=appstate
app uses the code and retrieves a token via /oauth/token

however, the custom chrome tabs browser is doing something really odd which I can see using the mobile chrome dev tools to investigate the network requests:
after the SAML assertion comes back, (which redirects us back to /oauth2/authorize) we apparently redirect back to the app using the custom protocol myapp://callback?code=12345&state=  (the dev console shows us that the redirect target is indeed the custom protocol)
HOWEVER, the custom chrome browser appears to attempt to repeat the authentication by going back to the sign in page...We can observe in the custom tabs dev console that a NEW GET request is made again to /accounts/signin (with no apparent initiator for this GET request at all. Unlike the first redirect to /accounts/signin from /oauth2/authorize which is expected since the user was not authenticated). We can confirm that the redirect back from the SAML assertion to /oauth2/authorize detects that the authentication was already done (cookie present) and continues forward to redirect to myapp://callback with the authorization code.
The second unexpected new request to the sign in page due to the presence of the cookie sees that we are already authenticated so it in turn redirects back to /oauth/authorize, which in turn tries to go back to the app...
Since the server received two different authorization requests, and we are unable to determine which of the redirects back to the app we are getting, the app will in most cases attempt to redeem an invalid code (via /oauth2/token).
This behavior does NOT occur on other devices using the exact same flow for client apps (e.g. iOS does not exhibit this behavior despite using the exact same workflow)
